# Pandas sort_index gives strange result after applying function to grouped DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Basic setup:

I have a `DataFrame` with a `MultiIndex` on both the rows and the columns.  The second level of the column index has `float`s for values.

I want to perform a `groupby` operation (grouping by the first level of the row index).  The operation will add a few columns (also with `float`s as their labels) to each group and then return the group.

When I get the result back from my `groupby` operation, I can't seem to get the columns to sort properly.

Working example.  First, set things up:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

col_level_1 = ['red', 'blue']
col_level_2 = [1., 2., 3., 4.]

row_level_1 = ['a', 'b']
row_level_2 = ['one', 'two']

col_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([col_level_1, col_level_2], names=['color', 'numeral'])
row_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([row_level_1, row_level_2], names=['letter', 'number'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(row_idx), len(col_idx)), index=row_idx, columns=col_idx)
```

Gives this `DataFrame` in `df`:
[image]

Then define my group operation and apply it:

```
def mygrpfun(group):
    for f in [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]:
        group[('red', f)] = 'hello'
        group[('blue', f)] = 'world'
    return group

result = df.groupby(level='letter').apply(mygrpfun).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Displaying `result` gives:
[image]

What's going on here?  Why doesn't the 2nd level of the column index display in ascending order?

EDIT:
In terms of context:

```
pd.__version__
Out[28]:
'0.14.0'
In [29]:

np.__version__
Out[29]:
'1.8.1'
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: can u post your pandas/numpy versions. maybe an issue sorting the float index

Comment: posted above, thanks Jeff

Answer (score 1):

The returned result looks as expected.  You added columns.  There was no guarantee that order imposed on those columns.

You could just reimpose ordering:

```
result = result[sorted(result.columns)]
```

Comment: While that's a good alternative, I think the OP was expecting the call to `sort_index(axis=1)` to achieve the same result.

Comment: unutbu, that's exactly right.  Why isn't the `sort_index` call getting the job done?