# Pandas sort_index fails with MultiIndex containing floats as one level (when columns are added)

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to distill the issue raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275057/pandas-sort-index-gives-strange-result-after-applying-function-to-grouped-datafr) down to its essence.  It seems like `DataFrame.sort_index` fails when the index in question has more than one level and one of those levels has numerical values in it if you try to perform the sort after adding columns.

Here's what I mean.  First, set up (note that the columns are out of "order" in all both `DataFrame`s and that `4` is "missing"):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randn(3,4)

df_single_float = pd.DataFrame(data, index=list('abc'), columns=[1., 3., 2., 5.])
df_multi_float = pd.DataFrame(data, index=list('def'), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('red', i) for i in [1., 3., 2., 5.]]))

df_list = [df_single_float, df_multi_float]
```

That gets us here:

```
for df in df_list:
    print df

          1         3         2         5
a  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
b  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357
c -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
        red                              
          1         3         2         5
d  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
e  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357
f -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
```

So far so good.  Now let's sort these:

```
for df in df_list:
    print df.sort_index(axis=1)

          1         2         3         5
a  1.764052  0.978738  0.400157  2.240893
b  1.867558  0.950088 -0.977278 -0.151357
c -0.103219  0.144044  0.410599  1.454274
        red                              
          1         2         3         5
d  1.764052  0.978738  0.400157  2.240893
e  1.867558  0.950088 -0.977278 -0.151357
f -0.103219  0.144044  0.410599  1.454274
```

That worked perfectly.  In all both cases, the columns come out in the natural order.  Let's add a column to each data frame:

```
df_single_float[4.0] = 'hello'
df_multi_float[('red', 4.0)] = 'world'

for df in df_list:
    print df   

          1         3         2         5      4
a  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  hello
b  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357  hello
c -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274  hello
        red                                  red
          1         3         2         5      4
d  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  world
e  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357  world
f -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274  world
```

Still looking good here.  The new columns wind up on the right.  And since we did *not* sort inplace above, the old columns are "out of order".  As expected.  But now let's try to sort these `DataFrame`s and see how they look:

```
for df in df_list:
    print df.sort_index(axis=1)

          1         2         3      4         5
a  1.764052  0.978738  0.400157  hello  2.240893
b  1.867558  0.950088 -0.977278  hello -0.151357
c -0.103219  0.144044  0.410599  hello  1.454274
        red                                  red
          1         2         3         5      4
d  1.764052  0.978738  0.400157  2.240893  world
e  1.867558  0.950088 -0.977278 -0.151357  world
f -0.103219  0.144044  0.410599  1.454274  world
```

And here we see the issue I'm trying to highlight: the regular old `Index`ed `DataFrame` sorts properly.  But the `MultiIndex`ed `DataFrame` does not seem to sort properly.  I have confirmed that the behavior is the same when using `int` instead of `float` numbers for where I have `[1., 3., 2., 5.]` above.  Am I doing something wrong here?  This doesn't seem like it's the expected behavior for what you should get back from sorting something, does it?

---

Adding version info:

```
pd.__version__
Out[9]:
'0.14.0'
In [10]:

np.__version__
Out[10]:
'1.8.1'
```

---

Edit in light of comment on `sortlevel`.  I don't think that works:

```
print df_multi_float.sortlevel(axis=1)

        red                                  red
          1         2         3         5      4
d  1.764052  0.978738  0.400157  2.240893  world
e  1.867558  0.950088 -0.977278 -0.151357  world
f -0.103219  0.144044  0.410599  1.454274  world
```

Comment: you need to use ``sortlevel`` to sort it (since ``sort_index`` does not have a ``level`` argument)

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to improve it for me.  Same issue.  See above.  Do you get a different result?

Comment: hmm, might be a bug, pls file a report on github (show the minimalist example possible)

Comment: Filed here https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8017